# How to get a UTF8 encoded string from a Base64 encoded string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, base64, utf-16

`AEEAQgBDAGEAYgBj` is Base64 for `ABCabc` however when I run this code:

```
let a = Buffer.from('AEEAQgBDAGEAYgBj', 'base64').toString('utf-8');
console.log(Buffer.from(a, 'utf8'));
```

the printed result in the console is `<Buffer 00 41 00 42 00 43 00 61 00 62 00 63>` which is UTF16 (LE).

I would assume that since I am creating a Buffer from a UTF8 encoded string the result would be `<Buffer 41 42 43 61 62 63>`.
So how can I get an actual UTF8 encoded string from Base64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your original data is Base64 encoded UTF16-BE. If you look at `a` after your first line, you'll see that it has those zero bytes that you see in the final buffer:

```
let a = Buffer.from("AEEAQgBDAGEAYgBj", "base64").toString("utf-8");
console.log(a.length);
// 12
console.log([...a].map(ch => ch.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join(" "));
// 00 41 00 42 00 43 00 61 00 62 00 63
```

So the question becomes: How to read the UTF16-BE text you have in the buffer from `Buffer.from("AEEAQgBDAGEAYgBj", "base64")`. Node.js's `Buffer` doesn't support UTF16-BE directly (there is no `"utf16be"` encoding in its standard library), but you can get there via [`swap16`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_swap16) and then reading the buffer as UTF16-LE (`"utf16le"`, which *is* in Node.js's standard library):

```
let a = Buffer.from("AEEAQgBDAGEAYgBj", "base64").swap16().toString("utf16le");
console.log(a.length);
// 6
console.log(a);
// ABCabc
```

Now `a` is a normal string. If you want a buffer containing its contents in UTF8, you can use `Buffer.from(a).toString("utf8")`:

```
let a = Buffer.from("AEEAQgBDAGEAYgBj", "base64").swap16().toString("utf16le");
console.log(a.length);
// 6
console.log(a);
// ABCabc
let b = Buffer.from(a); // (Default is `"utf8"` but you could supply that explicitly)
console.log(b);
// <Buffer 41 42 43 61 62 63>
```